# how to interpolate a value into an HTML attribute without binding to anything on the Vue instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The title was kinda long-winded but the question itself is pretty simple.

So I'm looping over some strings and want to make a button for each. On click, the button will call a Vue method. I want to bind the string into the HTML element somehow - it will be more clear with the code:

```html
<li v-for="(name, idx) in $store.state.lobby" :key="idx">
  <button data-name="{{name}}" v-on:click='send_game_request'> request game </button>
</li>
```

so, as you can see, this is very simple. When the `send_game_request` method gets run, it can read the `name` off the `data-name` attribute and do what it needs to with that information.

But, this is invalid syntax, because `{{name}}` raises an error.  I'm really hoping I *don't* have to wrap each button into it's own sub-component, because that is just extra boilerplate that's not necessary.

I've seen other examples that use `v-bind` but I don't really have any need to store this information in the component's internal state. I literally just need to know what button was pressed.

Comment: *without binding to anything on the Vue instance* ...well your data **is bound to Vue instance** because you are using `$store.state.lobby` - sure `$store` is injected by Vuex but it is still property of Vue instance. In fact it is not possible to use any data in the template which is **not available on the Vue instance**...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what Tony mentions in his answer,

```
<li v-for="(name, idx) in $store.state.lobby" :key="idx">
  <button :data-name="name" v-on:click='send_game_request'> request game </button>
</li>
```

You could then extract value of name with datasets like so:

```js
function send_game_request(event){
  const name = event.target.dataset.name;
}
```

NOTE: In this instance you don't need to explicitly pass the `$event` into your `v-on:click` function binding, it will already be made available by Vue. So, you can simply invoke your method with the event argument.

Comment: The downside to this approach is it requires storing data in the DOM, and relying on that data. A tech savvy user could easily edit the button's attributes before clicking it, so you'd have to watch out for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the `name` as an argument with an [inline handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers):

```html
<button @click="send_game_request($event, name)">
```

where `$event` is the original event data.

Comment: I think I'm gonna have to accept nishkaush's answer because it more accurately reflects what I was asking in the question. But your approach is the one I will actually use in my code :) Thank you